# Fell on the goalline

Tags: java

So I coded something that calculates the minimum and the maximum floating numbers that the user entered.

Now I got a follow up question that asked me to store the min and max numbers in a file.

Storing the min and max werent any problems, just did an outputfile print statement which said this is the biggest number + min (min was the variable). Vice versa for Max variable.

But im struggeling with getting every number the user entered before it calculated which number was the biggest and smallest.

Did outputfile print statement which " (min + max + number); but it only stored min, max, and the last entered number by the user, and not all between.

Do I need to make new variables to track every entered floated number? Or do I need to connect some other variables?

Ive tried using arrays but cant get a hang of it.

Look at this file, its how far ive came yet ; https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwpob.jpg

There might be another way thats more appropriate, dont hesitate to change, w/e just so it works.

I hope you can understand me.

Looking forward your suggestion.

Using Java

`import java.io.*; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Output {

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException //Eftersom vi inte lärt oss att hantera exceptions än
{
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Boo\\Desktop\\output.txt");  //Öppnar en ny fil



    // Variabel för att förvara "flyttal"

    float nummer;

    float array[]=null;

    //Deklarera max variabeln för att hålla största numret

    //Initialisera max med minimum värde möjligt

    float max=Float.MIN_VALUE;

    //Deklarera min variabeln för att hålla minsta numret

    //Initialisera min med maximum värde möjligt

    float min=Float.MAX_VALUE;

    //char variabel för att förvara Y/N, med andra ord är du klar?

    char yn;

    //scanner för att läsa input

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Start entering floating point numbers");

    do {

    //läs float input

    nummer = keyboard.nextFloat();

    if(max<nummer) //om max är mindre än nuvarande nummer

    max = nummer; //Då uppdateras max till nuvarande nummer

    if(min>nummer) //om min är större än nuvarande nummer

    min = nummer; //Uppdatera min till nuvarande nummer

    // Fråga användaren om inmatandet är klart?

    System.out.print("Are you done? (Y/N)?");


    yn = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

    // En loop som går tills användaren skriver n/N
    }while(yn=='N' || yn=='n'); 

    // Printar sen då resultatet, dvs högsta och minsta numret

    System.out.println("Biggest number entered is: "+max);

    System.out.println("Smallest number entered is: " +min);
    outputFile.println("Biggest number entered is:" +  min);
    outputFile.println("Smallest number entered is:" + max);
    outputFile.println("All of the numbers entered is:" +  );
    System.out.println("Data written to the file.");

    outputFile.close();
}
}
```

Comment: I cant see where are you adding the user numbers to the array

Comment: I havent, cus its "scanner user" based. So I dont know which numbers to add, hence the "null" to show you im lost.

Comment: When you read `nummer` add it to the array. However, before you can do that, you have to allocate the array with `new`. You should probably read a [tutorial on arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: I've been reading alot on arrays in java textbook and on oracle, but I just cant get a hang of it. Been struggeling with this last part over 5 hours now..
Hence the cry for help here.

Comment: Set a proper headline that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

When using arrays, you need to allocate space for the data. This means you need to know ahead of time the number of items you need:

```
float array[] = new float[100];
```

This will create an array with space for 100 `float`s.

Then, add all the numbers to the array as you read them from the user:

```
int currentIndex= 0; // Keep track of where to put the next number
do {
    nummer = keyboard.nextFloat();
    array[currentIndex++] = nummer;
    // .....
} while(currentIndex < 100 && (yn == 'N' || yn == 'n'));
```

Note that I've added a check that ensures you don't add anything once the array is full.

Lastly, use a loop to write all the values in the file.

```
outputFile.println("All of the numbers entered:" +  );
for (int i = 0; i < currentIndex; i++) {
    outputFile.println(array[i]);
}
```

Notes: There are other containers, like [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), that do not require you to know how many items you will need ahead of time.